# Laravel 5.1 Application don't have any route

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I create few route but don't display any route.
[image: Code dislpayed]

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, make sure that **routes.php** file is loaded in your **RouteServiceProvider**. You should see the following in its **map()** method:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
  $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
    require app_path('Http/routes.php');
  });
}
```

**Secondly**, it you have route caching enabled, it might happen that you've cached empty list of routes before any routes were added on **routes.php** and now are reusing the cached version. Run **php artisan route:clear** and then **php artisan route:list** - if that was the reason, you should see new all the routes.